# relacion base de datos DER

Tags: postgresql

Hola tengo una duda con bases de datos de una aplicacion que estoy haciendo recién voy por el DER y tengo una duda el asunto es:
un usuario puede tener muchos canales relacion de 1 a N

un usuario puede estar subscrito a muchos canales y el canal puede tener muchos subscriptores relacion de N a N.

mi duda es como hago esto en el der? saco dos relaciones de la entidad usuario hacia la entidad canal? .ayuda porfavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si un usuario tiene muchos canales y un canal puede tener muchos usuarios como bien dices es una relación N a N, por lo que deberías crear un entidad débil, en la cual tendrías dos llaves foráneas el id_usuario y el id_canal, ademas que en esta tabla podrías agregar información adicional como el periodo de la subscriptor. entre otras cosas.

Entonces en resumen tendrías que crear la tabla suscriptores_canales con los campos id_usuario, id_canal, etc.